# Excel - How do I create a running numeric total from a text category

Tags: excel

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]I need to add totals of 214 different categories as they run down 14,181 rows in Excel.

For example, "England" in cell A52 has a value of "8" and I need that value added to all previous values for "England" (NOT value after the current cell).

Basically, a running cumulative total for categories.

I'm guessing it needs the VLOOKUP, $A$2:B2, 2, FALSE. Any ideas?

Comment: Put few sample data

Comment: A picture of a few sample data and showing where you want the running total to be would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like this can be solved by subtotals. Data --> Subtotal

Comment: So I have a formula running down the D column to calculate a score. But I need running totals for the Team AND Against columns (B & C) in columns F & G, which SUM the value of D (in F), and E (in G) AND all previous values associated with that country. Does that make sense?!

Comment: So if I take Moldova as example, F2 should be -1, F9 should be -1+0=-1, F15 should be -1+-1=-2 ?

Comment: I've just realised that the rows aren't necessarily alternating, so I'll edit the d3 column now. But yes, Moldova would also have a 0 from D9 - in addition to the -1 in D2 and -1 in D15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMIF` with a partially locked range:

```
=SUMIF(B$2:B2,B2,D$2:D2)
```

(I highlighted Moldova in the picture since we confirmed it in the comments)

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, but would there be a way of grabbing the Against total in the G column? All games are duplicated, and not necessarily in the immediate row beneath. So it would need the most recent total for that country from the Team column. Is that possible using SUMIF, or would that be VLOOKUP?

Comment: @user2020088 I'm not sure I fully understand. Can you tell for example in G2 of my picture, what should be the value and why?

Comment: It's ok, I duplicated the formula and made it work with this. Many thanks for your help.